# Permission Denied when moving files using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

Getting the below error while executing PowerShell script

```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\domain\tm1server.log:FileInfo) [Move-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the sourcce directory as a PSDrive as well. Because the log in I used to the server didn't have WRITE acccess to the server.
So, I declared the sourcce directory as another PSDrive and used my ADMIN credential for creating it. 
After that I was able to use `move-item`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use `Copy-Item` to move your file to the destination.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Move-Item) for `Move-Item` states:

> The locations must be **supported by the same provider**. For example, it can
>   move a file or subdirectory from one directory to another or move a
>   registry subkey from one key to another. When you move an item, it is
>   added to the new location and deleted from its original location.

Comment: `copy-item` doesn't work either, getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

The folder specified in -path needs modify in addition to Read permission.   Modify and write permission is needed on the -destination folder.